Workaround MotoSim trial denial on virtual machine
I'm trying to run MotoSim EG-VRC 2024 for trial period in VirtualBox, Windows 10 on Linux.
When installing Demo License, I get a warning that VMs aren't supported:

Although the installation succeeds.
But, as warned, when running MotoSim, after approving the prompt to activate a 90 days trial,

there's an error message:

So, the question is: is there a workaround to activate the trial anyway? Maybe a demo license that mimics the hardware key?
